# setTheme is not changing toolbars

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-theme, android-styles

I'am trying to change whole app theme using

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_ONE);
    helper = new PreferenceHelper(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Base application theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ONE" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/red_800</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red_100</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/red_A700</item>
</style>
```

but nothing is changing to the toolbar :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
```

or any layout in the app that use colorPrimary.
i have been looking for alot of answers about changing manifest and putting settheme before super.oncreate but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After while i found out that you cant override setTheme if im using default names such as (`PrimaryColor` + `PrimaryDarkColor` + `AccentColor`) it worked after i changed it to 
(`DefaultPrimary` + `DefaultPrimaryDark` + `DefaultAccent`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the setTheme(..) call after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState).

Comment: I'm sorry, honestly, I don't clearly get what you want. Do you want to set the theme for just one activity or whole activity?

Comment: need it for all

Comment: Have you put the setTheme on all activity?

Comment: i did in basicActivity for whole app

Comment: Can you try to remove the android:theme attribute from your AppBarLayout? Let the setTheme() method do the work.